# Firebase Auth crash swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to setup Firebase auth sign in for my swift app which I have done on many other apps before with no problem, however for some reason I keep getting this error this time:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFURLSessionConfiguration_Mutable setTLSMinimumSupportedProtocolVersion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x121f941b0'

*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c6d2b9f0 0x1c72384fc 0x1c6c306ac 0x1c6d2fd40 0x1c6d3178c 0x103448980 0x103446a4c 0x100bc368c 0x100bc60f0 0x100bc462c 0x100bc297c 0x100bb2b80 0x100bb4428 0x100bb2e3c 0x100bb251c 0x104659874 0x10465ac50 0x104661bc8 0x104662768 0x10466db74 0x1c7578f5c 0x1c757baa0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

It only happens when running on an iPad on iOS13, and it was happening on an iPhone running iOS 13.2, however it then seemed to fix itself for no apparent reason. The problem has never happened when running on a simulator.

Using code from docs:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailInput.text!, password: passwordInput.text!) { [weak self] user, error in
     guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
}
```

Comment: check for nil of   emailInput.text! and  passwordInput.text! Verify to have GoogleService-Info.plist in your project

Comment: have tried hard coding value for email and password so error isnt there, tried redownloading the GoogleService-Info still not working

Answer (score 0):

inside your `didFinishLaunching` function in App delegate add this line.

```
FIRApp.configure()
```

Comment: Have got  ```FirebaseApp.configure()``` in my app delegate already, still not working

Comment: Are u sure that problem occurs due to you implement firebase ? Probably this problem is just about removing outlet-button issue. Please check your every step before you implement firebase into your app there maybe some deleting things cause a crush in somehow.

Comment: Double checked the implementation and added break points - crash is occuring when ```Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailInput.text!, password: passwordInput.text!) ``` is called, however its wierd that the problem is only occuring on one device

Comment: when you running app on iPad are you use emulator ? If it so some kind of network connection might be occurs.

Comment: No, on a physical iPad